# Setting PHP remote write permissions in IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, php, iis

I have two windows server 2008 servers. One is a web server one is a file server. A php script runs on the web server and is supposed to write to the other server. I am getting a permissions error.

I have given the full UNC path in the php copy command. I also gave IUSR read write permissions and it is still not working.

Comment: It depends a bit on how you have PHP set up, but for starters have you looked at the identity of the application pool its running under and tried giving that identity permissions?

Comment: I set it as my domain account and it still is giving permission errors.

Comment: On the destination server try the user: `[SERVER NAME]\NETWORK SERVICE`

Comment: Is the problem only with writing?  Have you tested if reading works? (PS. Yes, I know this question is very old.)